# Syntax Error after upgrading to Meteor 1.2

Tags: meteor

I'm getting an intermittent error reported in the browser after upgrading to Meteor 1.2:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

The page then does not load.

No errors are reported in the logs, so I've no idea how to go about figuring out what could be wrong.

Could anyone suggest possible issues or ways to detect them?

Comment: that's usually just a problem in es6 compilation

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the `ecmascript` package hides the actual errors you can't really debug it, try to `meteor remove ecmascript` and you will see straightforward error. Fix and restore the package with `meteor add ecmascript` It worked for me.